# How to handle redirection using a POST request with Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a page located in `url_1` using `requests.get(url_1)`.

However this request triggers a redirection to `url_2` and as a result the content I get is obviously not from `url_1`.

The page located in `url_2` is a disclaimer where the "accept" button must be pushed before accessing to `url_1`.

I have already retrieved the parameters of the POST request in order to move from `url_2` to `url_1` using Firefox, but I don't see exactly how to handle the redirection in Python in a way that I could input that POST request so that I can download the page located in `url_1`.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an option with requests allowing auto redirect on `301` :

```py
requests.post("url", allow_redirects=True)
```